# How many nodes do you need to complete to get 100% your Age of Triumph book?

Tags: destiny

I have been recently grinding both PvP and PvE to finish my book and I have about 3 and several other pages almost done and i'm only at 88%, so i am wondering how many nodes does it take to reach 100% in the book?

Comment: I haven't played recently but if this record book is like any others then you can just count the ones that are missing.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Well that's the thing, the Destiny staff said you don't need to complete everything in the book to get 100%

Comment: No, they said that for getting all the *rewards*

Comment: oh, i see what you mean, i edetid my question to try to narrow my question down

Comment: I don't have an exact amount, but I remember Bungie saying you need to unlock about 75% of the book in order to get to rank 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Age of Triumph Megathread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/627mrs/age_of_triumph_ask_your_questions_here_megathread/) on the DestinytheGame subreddit, you need to fill in 75% of the nodes.

You *will* need the completion percentage to hit 100%, as that's the progress towards rank 7, but you do not need to complete every page in the book to get there. However, it seems that some nodes are worth 1% towards progress and others are worth 2%.

The general consensus seems to be that ~61-63 nodes is enough to get you to level 7.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete the Age of Triumph book to 100%, you don't need to do EVERY page or node.  I don't have an exact percentage, but I was able to hit 100% completion without having almost any of my Trials of Osiris page done, the Raid page not quite done, the Crucible page not done, the Warlock page not done, and the first node for doing an activity between launch and Dark Below unobtainable for me.